# Assign customer group to payment method

Tags: payment-methods, customer-group, magento-1.4

One of my customer came with a problem after he added a new customer group to his Magento store. Currently he has multiple groups and all are working fine. The only problem is when he tries to create a new order (from inside the back-end) and he selects the payment method where they get 3% discount, the discount isn't calculated into the final price.
If he does the same with a random different customer group (created years ago) the discount will be calculated correctly.

I've been searching for a configuration where we connected the two with each other. Unfortunate no results so far.

Hope someone run into this problem before.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: where is the discount calculated? are you using shopping cart price rules?

Comment: Discount is calculated after a payment method and secondly a shipment method is selected. But only if the customer group is different than the 5% group. (via 'sales_order_create/index/customer_id/1/') not sure if this is a custom module or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all the shopping cart price rules (Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules) that are conditioned by shipping and payment methods (under the Conditions tab). Inside those rules check the customer groups for which they can apply.

Comment: You are my hero for today. I knew it had to be somewhere and I looked everywhere for this single window :D Thank you so much!

Comment: can you tell me what the condition apply to payment method?. My Condition is `If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    Payment Method  is  Cash On Delivery 
       `  then i've select the customer group from Rule information tab but it's not working.